# Combine MySQL SELECT COUNTs

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have 3 MySQL queries I'd like to combine as 1

```sql
SELECT pic FROM active,
SELECT pic FROM deleted,
SELECT alt_pic FROM active where alt_pic!=''
```

I've managed to get the first 2 as one

```sql
SELECT pic FROM active UNION SELECT pic FROM deleted
```

I think I've partially gotten through combining all 3 except I don't know where exactly to insert the 3rd query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT pic FROM active UNION SELECT pic FROM deleted)t
```

I am just studying for fun. If I am somehow breaking convention or introduce some security risks, please don't get mad :)

Edit 1: Newbie doesn't know, thanks Mureinik and Strawberry for pointing it out :)
alt_pic is just a very optional field, my table `active` has about 300+ rows but only 8 alt_pic fields filled

```
active
ID | name  | pic      | alt_pic
1  | Peter | pic5.jpg | alt1.jpg
2  | Mark  | pic4.jpg | NULL
3  | John  | pic3.jpg | alt2.jpg

deleted
ID | pic
1  | pic2.jpg
2  | pic1.jpg
```

The result I'd like to have is

```
pic_count | alt_pic_count
5         | 2
```

Comment: You can SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... UNION SELECT .... UNION SELECT ... as much as you want

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: @Mureinik and Strawberry thank you for pointing that out, I've edited it already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd perform an aggregate query on each table, and then, since they both return just one row, cross join them. Note you don't need a third query with a condition on `alt_pic` - since `count` ignores `null`s, you could apply it directly to that column.

```sql
SELECT     pcount + dcount AS pic_count, acount AS alt_pic_count
FROM       (SELECT COUNT(pic) AS pcount, COUNT(alt_pic) AS acount
            FROM   active) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS dcount 
            FROM   deleted) d
```

Comment: Its perfect! Thank you very much :))))))))))))))